# How should my package.xml look like to retrieve EVERY object with its fields?

Tags: metadata-api, package.xml

I'm trying to build the `package.xml` in order to retrieve every single object with all its *retriavable* fields (I am aware that some fields cannot be retrieved), but I can't seem to achieve it.

When I include this in the file:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

It only brings me the custom objects and the standard with the custom fields, but not the standard objects with the standard retrievable fields.

How should I make my package file to retrieve everything in one go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the documentation- [Sample package.xml Manifest Files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm), it looks like you would have to specify the name of objects explicitly:

> ## Standard Objects
>
> ```
> <types>
>     <members>Account</members>
>     <name>CustomObject</name>
> </types>
> ```
>
> You cannot use an asterisk wildcard to work with all standard objects; each standard object must be specified by name.
>
> ## All Custom Objects
>
> ```
> <types>
>     <members>*</members>
>     <name>CustomObject</name>
> </types>
> ```
>
> This manifest file can be used to retrieve or deploy all custom
>   objects. **This does not include all standard objects.**

Add members to your types on custom objects to specify additional custom objects along with one having wild card character (`*`), an example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <members>Account</members>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: So I understand I would need to include several <member> tags nested in the <types> for CustomObject? That would be one with the wildcard, and another extra for each standard object?

Comment: Yes, you should explicitly specify standard objects as additional members.

Comment: It is a little confusing that the standard objects are in the CustomObject type and to get all of them would mean a lot of extra lines in the package.

Comment: @DaveHumm it is... but it does seem like it's the only way though. I think SF should update their APIs some day lmao

Comment: @RahulSharma regarding the CustomFields, would the same thing be necessary or by including the Object are they also included (std + custom)?

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano, custom fields should be available when you add standard objects, please try and let us know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Raul's approach did not work for me. In my testing, the wildcard on its own pulls custom objects. A specified list on its own can pull standard objects. But combining them in a single manifest just went with the wildcard behavior. I am using API version 52.

My workaround is to retrieve twice with separate manifests.

package-standardObjects.xml

```
...    
<types>        
            <members>Account</members>
            <members>AccountBrand</members>
            <members>AccountContactRelation</members>
            <members>AccountContactRole</members>
            <members>Activity</members>
            ...
            <members>WorkRewardFundType</members>
            <members>WorkThanks</members>
            <name>CustomObject</name>
        </types>  
...
```

package.xml

```
...
<types>        
    <members>*</members>        
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
...
```

pipeline.yml

```
...
    sfdx force:source:retrieve -x package-standardObjects.xml --verbose
    sfdx force:source:retrieve -x package.xml --verbose 
...
```